# How to create a JMeter Plugin

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I've been trying to figure out how to add on to the functionality of JMeter for a couple days, and I'm sort of stumped. I basically want to build a testing functionality of a proprietary DB (it's not too important on the specifics here). However, the issue I am encountering is where to even begin with the creation of the functionality.

I've tried various stuff on the [JMeter website (an example)](http://jmeter.apache.org/building.html) and [the wiki (an example)](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/BuildingPlugInWithEclipse), but it all boils down to I can't seem to find a repository which I can pull into eclipse (or with just building with ant, I can't seem to download_jars because it can't connect to the repo listed in there). Is there any up to date resources on how to build a JMeter plug in? Or am I doing something wrong here because I am inexperienced in setting up something like this?

Any help is greatly appreciated, but please don't just link the first thing on google; I have done quite a bit of searching already. Thanks!

Edit: It turned out the reason I couldn't get eclipse working with a repo was due to the network restrictions I had to deal with. When I tried on another computer/network, it worked fine. I used [this jmeter tutorial](http://people.apache.org/~mkostrze/jmeter-eclipse/index.html), but since it is out of date regarding the repository (they use SVN now), I used http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter as the root using subclipse. In case anyone runs into the same problem I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also searched for a building jmeter plugin for my graph plugin stuff. I got a simple and good source code from  **Ruben laguna's** blog. You can understand the basic structure and steps to create jmeter plugin.

Check out this:

**Graph plugin** - http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/better-jmeter-graphs/
**Enhanced-jdbc-sampler** - http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/enhanced-jdbc-sampler-for-apache-jmeter-22/